# How to animate through a list of elements using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, animation, loops, chaining

I have a list items of cars that I'd like to animate through.

```
<li id="toyota">
    <img class="car" src="img/toyota.png">
</li>
<li id="honda">
    <img class="car" src="img/honda.png">
</li>
<li id="ford">
    <img class="car" src="img/ford.png">
</li>
```

I'm assuming I'd have to store them in an array and then loop through them?

I'm pretty new to jQuery/JS, but I sort of understand the concepts. I want to animate through each car so that one appears after another. Something like this:

```
$('.car').fadeIn(1000, function(){
    $('.car').fadeOut(1000);
});
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following:

```
var cars = $('.car');
var index = 0;
var loop = function() {
  var car = $(cars[index]);
  car.fadeIn(1000, function() {
    car.fadeOut(1000, function() {
      index = index + 1 < cars.length ? index + 1 : 0;
      loop();
    });
  });
};
loop();
```

This will fadeIn a car, then fade it out, once it has faded out it will fadeIn the next car, continuing round to the first car again.

Comment: This seems like it almost did it. It's just only looping through the first car though :(

Comment: @hawsome, are you sure you copied it correctly? See http://jsfiddle.net/JmryA/ for jsFiddle showing above code working just fine!

Comment: It worked perfectly, sorry! I was just using a slideshow plugin that's messing with the opacity and display of the other list items so it was only showing the first slide :(

Thanks so much for the help! Also, is there a reason it's on an infinity loop? I was hoping it would stop after reaching the last slide.

Comment: Is there a way to do a callback once the last slide animation is completed? That way I could run the slideshow plugin after this intro runs it's course. Thanks!

Comment: @hawsome once `index + 1 === cars.length` all cars have been looped through - you could raise an event or call the slideshow plugin at this point

Comment: I tried adding an if statement surrounding the 'loop();' in the function inside, but it cuts off at the second to last image. Is there anyway to make it cut off after the last image? Thanks so much!

Comment: Here's my code now http://pastie.org/2977871. Sorry, my original post omitted a lot of the actual code for simplicity sake.

Comment: do you think if I change `index + 1 === cars.length` to `index + 1 === cars.length + 1` it will work?

Comment: Never mind, Reddit to the rescue! http://www.reddit.com/r/javascript/comments/n3gf7/jquery_issue_with_animating_through_a_list_of/

Comment: @rich.okelly I just snaffled this code, it solved a problem I've been struggling with for a couple of days. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4):

```
var delay = 100;
// iterate through each li element and run a method
$('li').each(function (index, el) {
    $(el).delay(delay * index).fadeIn(1000, function (){
        $(this).fadeOut(1000);
    });
});
```

If you are looking for a slideshow type of interaction check out: http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/

Comment: Cool, thanks, I need to fadeOut this element now, and then move to the next all the way to the end. Do you know how I could do this? After fading in the first element it stops.

Comment: `fadeIn` provides a secondary paramater for a callback just as you did in your question. Throw the fadeOut call inside of there.  See my edit.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should have a look at jQuery Cycle.

http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/

Answer (score 0):

Using the each method will parse through each element in the jQuery collection one at a time instead of using implicit iteration. Like so:

```
$(".car").each(function() {
    $(this).fadeOut(1000);
});
```

[.each()](http://api.jquery.com/each/)

Comment: Yeah, I figured this was the solution, I was just wondering how to go to the next car. It stops after fading out the first car. Is there a way to introduce the second car? All the way until it hits the end. Would I need to create an array for that?